# Reroute iPhone audio through speaker,headphone or bluetooth

Tags: ios4

I would like to create an application which allows user to select the audio route. ie user can select whether audio to be played through headphone, speaker or bluetooth. My application is not playing any audio, but what i want is, if a song is playing in iPhone using built in Music App or any other media player, when i select speaker from my application the song should be played through speaker even if a headset is connected. Is it possible to control the system level audio routing from another application.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make something similar at one point. If I remember correctly... there is a physical switch in the device that gets closed when the headphones are inserted. Effectively making it impossible to route the sound, as there is no longer a any connections between the speakers and the rest of the device.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found better way than using a part of media player volume view.

Next is a code snippet:

```
// Display the audio route button (Bluetooth / Speaker / iPhone)
UIView *mpVolumeViewParentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 50, 40)];
mpVolumeViewParentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mpVolumeViewParentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

MPVolumeView *systemVolumeSlider = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-290, 0, 320, 40)];
[mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview:systemVolumeSlider];
[systemVolumeSlider release];

[self.view addSubview:mpVolumeViewParentView];
[mpVolumeViewParentView release];
```

This isn't the perfect solution but it does the work.

Comment: Thanks Michael, But does this provide options to switch between bluetooth, speaker and headset. I got only a volume slider. I didnt test with bluetooth.  My requirement is like, even if the headset is connected if user selects speaker audio should be routed through speaker. This feature is available in normal phones. Does this possible?

Comment: Actually, when I wrote this answer I have tested the solution only when the bluetooth is connected. If this is the case then you will get the possibility to switch the route just like you want. If there is no headset connected then it will look not good (you'll see a part of the volume slider). Just connect the headset to your device and put this code AS IS in the end of viewDidLoad. You should see the bluetooth icon. When you will touch it, a popup with audio route selection will appear. I will play with it a little in order to determine if headset is connected and show/hide the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, user control of audio routing only through either device activation or the volume control is Apple's intended user experience.  The thing the phone app does is not available to regular developers.

"Apps don't actually get to route audio wherever they want (not even Apple apps!)... we (under the hood) send the audio where the user wants it."

http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Oct/msg00030.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 4.2 MPVolumeView has two
properties to disable the unwanted elements:

```
showsVolumeSlider
showsRouteButton
```